# Switch case not affecting variable C

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    //Initialise variable for switch option
    int option = 0;
    //Set time to default to epoch
    char *argtime = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";
    //Use getopt to parse switches t and h (neither requires an argument, as epoch is defaulted to if non is supplied)
    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "th")) != -1) {
        //Switch statements for supplied switches
        switch (option) {
            //If -t
            case 't':
                //If arg supplied
                if(optarg != NULL) {
                    //Set arg to given arg 
                    argtime = optarg;
                }
                printf("-t is selected.\n");
                break;
            //If -h
            case 'h':
                printf("Help is selected\n");
                break;
            //If anything else
            default:
                printf("Option invalid\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The set time is %s\n", argtime);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's some code I wrote to use getopt() to parse a command line switch, and argument. I want it `argtime` to default to "1970-01-01 00:00:00" if no argument is supplied, which it does, but when I use the `-t` switch and supply a different argument, argtime remains unaffected. So basically `argtime = optarg;` is not doing what it should, but I don't know why.

Comment: Where is `optarg` defined?

Comment: And you checked with a debugger that that code path is taken and optarg is not null etc and still the variable doesn’t change?

Comment: Optarg is set by getopt to point at the value of the option argument, for those options that accept arguments.

Comment: That forces t to take an argument - but if one isn’t supplied I want argtime to default to what I set it

Comment: POSIX `getopt()` does not provide for optional arguments, and it's not clear that you need such a thing here.  But if you are willing to rely on GNU extensions, then the GNU version of `getopt()` recognizes a double colon for signifying an optional argument.

Comment: You told getopt that t does not have an argument, so it did not read the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `getopt()` about options that require an argument.  As @xing described in comments, you do that by putting a colon in the option string, after the option letter that is affected.  This allows `getopt()` to correctly handle grouped options and to recognize non-option arguments.  Only if you do this can you expect option arguments to be communicated to you via `optarg`.

You claim in comments to want an optional option argument.  POSIX-standard `getopt()` does not provide for that.  In your particular case, it's not clear why you even want it, for what would it mean to specify a `-t` option without an argument?  That the program should use a default?  But that's what it will do if `-t` is omitted altogether.

Nevertheless, the way to approach the situation with POSIX `getopt()` is to provide two separate options, one that takes an argument and one that doesn't.  For example, you might use option `-T` to signify whatever you wanted `-t` without an option to mean (`getopt(argc, argv, "t:Th")`).  Alternatively, if you are willing to rely on GNU extensions then you can signify an optional option argument via a double colon (`getopt(argc, argv, "t::h")`), but this is less portable, and has slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `optind` after the while to see if there is another argument and if so, use that argument instead of the default.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    //Initialise variable for switch option
    int option = 0;
    //Set time to default to epoch
    char *argtime = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";
    //Use getopt to parse switches t and h (neither requires an argument, as epoch is defaulted to if non is supplied)
    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "th")) != -1) {
        //Switch statements for supplied switches
        switch (option) {
            //If -t
            case 't':
                //If arg supplied
                printf("-t is selected.\n");
                break;
            //If -h
            case 'h':
                printf("Help is selected\n");
                break;
            //If anything else
            default:
                printf("Option invalid\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }
    if ( optind < argc) {//more arguments available
        //Set arg to given arg
        argtime = argv[optind];
    }

    printf("The set time is %s\n", argtime);
    return 0;
}
```